# ExtJS 4 to ExtJS 5 migration

Tags: javascript, extjs, web-applications, frameworks

We are migrating a web application from **ExtJS 4** to **ExtJS 5**.

Testing the **index.html** results in the following error (outputted by the **Firefox-FireBug-console**):

```
NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/ext/build/examples/ux/grid/FiltersFeature.js?_dc=1414147197935
```

I have already searched for the **FilterFeatures.js**-file inside the directory, but it isn't there.

According to the ["Whats New in ExtJS 5.0"-site](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/whats_new/5.0/whats_new.html) this file was so popular, that they thought it would be wise to move it.

**Can someone tell me how to include this file or the functionality, so that the error vanishes?**

I have already tried to add the following to my app.js file:

```
Ext.Loader.setPath('Ext.ux', './ext/build/examples/ux');
Ext.application({
    ...
    requires: [
        'Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature'
    ],
    ...
});
```

But the **error persists**. I think i need to get a **reference to an object** that is now hidden somewhere else.

I just dont know how to reference it, because i dont know the js-file it is now placed in and how to do it syntactically correct in Ext JS 5.

Comment: My suggestion is to strip down the application during your ExtJS upgrade so you add pieces at a time.  Running the entire app all at once might take you a lot longer to diagnose the actual issues.

Answer (score 1):

The basics are in the link you provided:

- They removed the **feature** `Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature` (ftype: filters).
- They introduced a **plugin** `Ext.grid.filters.Filters` (ptype: gridfilters)
  as an enhanced replacement.

So you will have to rework your grids manually to use the new plugin instead of the old feature.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Glad to share `Ext Js up gradation` experience , Please check this link [Ext Js 4 to 5 Migration Experience](http://www.quora.com/Did-someone-try-ExtJS-up-gradation-to-the-new-stable-5-1-0-version-Which-process-should-I-follow-to-upgrade-my-existing-ExtJS-4-2-1-to-5-1-0). Have a Happy Migration. Thanks