# Cannot upgrade to ExtJS 5

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs5

We are trying to upgrade to **ExtJS 5.1** from **ExtJS 4.x**

We replaced all the references to ExtJS 4 and added these two lines to the index :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/lib/ext-5.1.0/packages/ext-theme-crisp/build/resources/ext-theme-crisp-all-debug.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/ext-5.1.0/build/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
```

An error is thrown now when starting the application ;

> prefix table.packageListTable.InboxPackageTable ext-all-debug.js:5663
>   [E] "Ext.mixin.Observable#addEvents" is deprecated.log @
>   ext-all-debug.js:5663Ext.apply.raise @
>   ext-all-debug.js:1969Ext.Base.makeDeprecatedMethod @
>   ext-all-debug.js:6822Ext.define.init @
>   FiltersFeature.js?_dc=1429874149776:204Ext.define.initFeatures @
>   ext-all-debug.js:95661Ext.define.initComponent @
>   ext-all-debug.js:95440Ext.define.constructor @
>   ext-all-debug.js:38501Ext.Base.Base.addMembers.callParent @
>   ext-all-debug.js:7378Ext.define.constructor @
>   ext-all-debug.js:92913Ext.Base.Base.addMembers.callParent @
>   ext-all-debug.js:7378Ext.define.constructor @
>   ext-all-debug.js:95409constructor @ ext-all-debug.js:7657(anonymous
>   function) @ VM218:1Ext.ClassManager.Ext.apply.create @
>   ext-all-debug.js:8894Ext.define.getView @
>   ext-all-debug.js:90932Ext.define.initComponent @
>   ext-all-debug.js:90594Ext.Base.Base.addMembers.callParent @
>   ext-all-debug.js:7378Ext.define.initComponent @
>   AbstractGrid.js:153Ext.Base.Base.addMembers.callParent @
>   ext-all-debug.js:7378Ext.define.initComponent @ PackageGrid.js:29

This comes from AbstractGrid.js where there is a super call to parent from the initComponent() method. AbstractGrid.js is just a Grid component.

Any ideas what is going wrong here?

Comment: The exception is telling you exactly what the problem is.

Comment: addEvents are no longer supported. remove them from your code

Comment: Refer this for changes from 4 to 5 http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/whats_new/5.0/diff_changes.html and then this for 5.0 to 5.1 http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/whats_new/5.1.0/diff_changes.html

Comment: Or, check out all the changes - http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/

Comment: I think you'll get more of addEvents, so better scan you code for it and remove them all.

Comment: May be duplicate of this...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26546585/extjs-4-to-extjs-5-migration/29896550#29896550

Answer (score 1):

In your FiltersFeature.js on line 204 remove the addEvents method. AddEvents is not supported in Extjs 5.1

Btw. you can see this information in your callstack!