# Extjs 5 : Set Up for Dynamic Web Project

Tags: jakarta-ee, extjs, extjs5

I want to upgrade to Extjs 5, right now i am working on Extjs 4.

In order to use Extjs, i added selective folder and files and not complete Extjs folder.(i.e resources folder and two other files)

[image]

But now i want to upgrade to Extjs 5, But in SDK of Estjs 5, resources folder is missing.

[image]

Please help me out with the set-up of project.

Comment: May be duplicate of this...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26546585/extjs-4-to-extjs-5-migration/29896550#29896550

Answer (score 0):

You should add the files, if using the neptune theme for example:

- ext-5.1.0/build/ext-all.js
- ext-5.1.0/build/ext-all-debug.js
- ext-5.1.0/build/packages/ext-theme-neptune/build/resources/ext-theme-neptune-all.css
- ext-5.1.0/build/packages/ext-theme-neptune/build/resources/images

and if using charts

- ext-5.1.0/build/packages/sencha-charts/build/sencha-charts.js
- ext-5.1.0/build/packages/sencha-charts/build/sencha-charts-debug.js
- ext-5.1.0/build/packages/sencha-charts/build/neptune/

Uploading these files you will be able to work with ExtJS the same way you did with versions 3 and 4, however, now that you updating to ExtJS 5 I would suggest you install Sencha Command and run

```
sencha -sdk <path to extjs 5> generate app <yourappname> <yourAppFolder>
```

example

```
sencha -sdk ../../ext-5.1.0 generate app MyApp ./MyNewApp
```

Move your files to the new folder making use of the MVVM structure and then running

```
sencha app build production
```

This will only add the necessary files to your final build and theme, so you won't need a bulky ext-all.js in your production app.

Good Luck with your upgrade.